# In haskell loop exception without loop in its function body

Tags: haskell, ghci

I'm newbie to Haskell and write the following small code but it failed with loop exception. The problem is the code  doesn't use the loop , even recursion. 
That's make me crazy!

```
gameList :: [Int]->Int->Int->[(Int, Int)]
gameList  org pos step =
    let next  = (mod (pos + step)  2) ;
        pos = next;             
    in  [(pos, pos)]
```

Then save it in one file and succeed to load it into GHC with interactive mode.
invoke it like this 
           `gameList [1,2,3] 0  1`

It will throw error "[(*** Exception: <>"

The GHCI info :WinGHCi 1.0.6
Help me!

Comment: Infinite loop here because `pos` is one of your arguments. What are you trying to do? What is the expected output of `gameList [1,2,3] 0  1`?

Comment: BTW, you normally never need to end lines with semicolons in Haskell, nor do you need to surround definitions with parentheses.

Comment: The reason is that let expression is not assignment, it's defintion of block code.  In this case, it's recursive. The same case as the following code:    let t = (let pos = next; next = pos in (pos, next))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> doesn't use the loop , even recursion

This is not correct, here's why.

```
gameList :: [Int]->Int->Int->[(Int, Int)]
gameList  org pos step =              -- this is an unused argument named pos
  let next  = (mod (pos + step)  2) ; -- here we define next in terms of pos
        pos = next;                   -- ... which is defined here in terms of next
    in  [(pos, pos)]                  -- here we use this circularly-defined pos
```

See, `let` is not an assignment, and it is not "executed" top-to-bottom. `let` introduces a block of *mutually-recursive definitions*. So this

```
let next  = (mod (pos + step)  2) ;
    pos = next;
```

does not use `pos` the function argument at all.

Comment: Yes, I made that mistake  because I thought let expression will just assignment ,not block of code.   So It's hard for me to know why . Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

> "doesn't use a loop, even recursion"

I'm afraid it does actually use recursion, albeit in a way that isn't even possible in non-lazy languages!

The crux is that your parameter `pos` is never actually used anywhere, it's immediately shadowed by the `pos` defined in the `let` block (GHC would have warned you about that, with `-Wall`!). So your code is equivalent to

```
gameList org _ step =
    let next  = (mod (pos + step)  2) ;
        pos = next;             
    in  [(pos, pos)]
```

where `next` is defined in terms of `pos` which is defined in terms of `next` which is... and so on.

The obvious fix is to remove the line `pos = next`, which is completely unnecessary anyway.

```
gameList org pos step
  = let next  = (pos + step) `mod` 2
    in  [(next, next)]
```

Comment: I got the reason I misunderstand the meaning of let expression. It's not a assignment, it's block of code.  And also thanks your answer and suggestion on -Wall

Comment: It's a block of _definitions_, that's the crucial thing.